# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Data.Dataset' - returned result from SQL required

Tags: c#, sql

I am sending through a object with various parameters to SQL and need to receive a value of either 0 or 1 back, to indicate success or failure.

I have confirmed that all my parameters are sent through successfully to SQL, but I'm experiencing trouble regarding the "@Result" value that needs to be returned to C#.

Here is an extract of my code in the Data.cs file:

```
    public System.Data.DataSet spe_ISUpgradePossible(dbObject  currentDBObj)
    {
        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = GetCommand("spe_ISUpgradePossible", connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter parameter;

                parameter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ServicePack", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                parameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
                parameter.Value = currentDBObj.servicePack;
                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

                parameter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ServicePackFolder", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                parameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
                parameter.Value = currentDBObj.servicePackFolder;
                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

                parameter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Result", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
                parameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

                System.Data.DataSet dataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(command);
                adapter.Fill(dataSet);
                return dataSet;

                //int result = Convert.ToInt16(command.Parameters["@Result"].Value.ToString());
                //return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have added the following two lines to cater for the "@Result":

```
                        //int result = Convert.ToInt16(command.Parameters["@Result"].Value.ToString());
                //return result;
```

This have resulted in the following error being displayed: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Data.Dataset'"

Could someone please assist me in how to get around the above named problem? Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method requires a dataset to be returned not an integer

The problem is the line

```
 return result; // an integer
```

while the method states

```
 public System.Data.DataSet spe_ISUpgradePossible(dbObject  currentDBObj)
```

So you need to decide what to return to the calling code.
I feel that you need both infos, if this is the case, then you could change your method signature using an [out parameter](http://www.dotnetperls.com/out)

```
 public System.Data.DataSet spe_ISUpgradePossible(dbObject  currentDBObj, out int result)
 {
     ......
     // Assign the output parameter to the output variable passed in the method call
     result = Convert.ToInt32(command.Parameters["@Result"].Value.ToString());
     return dataSet;
 }
```

Notice also that you declare the output parameter to be of type integer, but then you convert it to a short int (`Convert.ToInt16`). This makes no sense (why loosing precision?) and thus it is better to stick with the original datatype of the output parameter (`Convert.ToInt32`)

After these changes you need to replace the calling code to reflect the new method signature and be absolutely sure that your `spe_ISUpgradePossible` doesn't return to the calling code without initializing the output parameter

```
 // No intialization here is needed, the out keyword forces the compiler to check
 // for every possible code path in the called method that return without `result` initialized
 int result;  
 Dataset ds = spe_ISUpgradePossible(yourObject, out result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation it does make sense. And yes I require both the input & output parameters.

I have made the required changes, but now has triggered a new error -  "No overload for method 'spe_ISUpgradePossible' takes 1 argument". I then added  "out int result" to the WebMethod, but this resulted in even more errors. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Something is wrong in how do you call the method. I will try to add an example in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your function that return `int` instead of `dataset`

Change this

```
public System.Data.DataSet spe_ISUpgradePossible(dbObject  currentDBObj)
```

into this

```
public int spe_ISUpgradePossible(dbObject  currentDBObj)
```